# Slope-One recommender implementation using mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to implement Slop-One recommender using mysql stored procedure, the query runs okay and doesn't give any error. But it is not inserting/updating the 'dev' table.
The structure of tables are:

```
rating (user_id, article_id, rating_value, date)

dev (article1_id, article2_id, count, sum)
```

The 'dev' table has joint primary key `(article1_id, article2_id)`. The sql for my procedure is as follows:

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_matrix(IN user INT(11), IN article INT(11), IN rating TINYINT(1))
    BEGIN
      DECLARE article_id2 INT(11);
      DECLARE rating_diff TINYINT(1);
      DECLARE done TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT article_id, (rating - rating_value)
        FROM rating
        WHERE user_id = user AND article_id != article;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
      OPEN mycursor;
        FETCH mycursor INTO article_id2, rating_diff;
        WHILE(!done) DO
          INSERT INTO dev (`article1_id`, `article2_id`, `count`, `sum`)
          VALUES (article, article_id2, 1, rating_diff)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1, sum = sum + rating_diff;

          INSERT INTO dev (`article1_id`, `article2_id`, `count`, `sum`)
          VALUES (article_id2, article, 1, -rating_diff)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1, sum = sum - rating_diff;

          FETCH mycursor INTO article_id2, rating_diff;
        END WHILE;
      CLOSE mycursor;
    END$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why not to try ready solution (not database)? Are you going to solve this matrix using database stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, I am planning on using stored procedures, my application is based on php and mysql, and the php version of this code is very slow.

Comment: There is already a implementation of Slope-One using stored procedure here at https://code.google.com/p/openslopeone/. But rather than updating the dev table on new rating, it is re-calculating the whole dev table from scratch. The procedure I have written is based on the actual publication of Slope-One http://lemire.me/fr/abstracts/SDM2005.html

Comment: Thanks. Interesting but I tried only Java approach.